# Loop through bulkcolumn SQL Server get values inbetween static strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I have an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column in SQL server that contains an HTML dump of one of our websites pages. I am particularly interested in the values between two static strings/tags within the column. I need all the data inbetween these static strings: `href="` and  `/" data-search`.

The column contains these two strings about 50 times and I need all 50 values between the strings, so I was thinking about using a cursor to loop through the column, but my SQL knowledge is kinda the bottleneck here.

Is there anyone that can help me building this query?

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @htmlString  nvarchar(Max)
declare @Id  int
declare @strtIndex  int
declare @endIndex  int
declare @href  nvarchar(Max)
declare @result table (Id int, href nvarchar(Max))

--replace this line with your query
set @htmlString = 
'<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
   </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <a href="/a/jiu/sddddddddd/"></a>
    <a href="/b/jiu/sddddddddd/"></a>
    <a href="/c/jiu/sddddddddd/"></a>
    <a href="/d/jiu/sddddddddd/"></a>
</body>
</html>'

set @Id = 0
WHILE LEN(@htmlString) > 0
BEGIN
    set @Id = @Id+1
    set @strtIndex = CHARINDEX('href="', @htmlString) + LEN('href="')
    set @endIndex = CHARINDEX('/"', @htmlString, @strtIndex)

    IF @endIndex > 0
        BEGIN
            set @href =SUBSTRING(@htmlString, @strtIndex, @endIndex-@strtIndex)
            insert into @result (Id , href)
            values(@Id , @href)
            SET @htmlString = SUBSTRING(@htmlString, @endIndex +1,LEN(@htmlString))
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @htmlString = NULL
        END
END

select * from @result
```